# Django creating record into a model with multiple foreign key fields

Tags: python, django

So i basically have a model called Designations that derives foreign keys from 3 other models (curricula, role and staff) and i am trying to save a new record into the Designations model, the code below shows the Designations and Staffs model.

```
class Designations(models.Model):
    designation_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    curriculum = models.ForeignKey(Curricula, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staffs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "arc_designations"
        unique_together = ('curriculum', 'role', 'staff')
        verbose_name_plural = "Designations"
        ordering = ['designation_id']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s %s (%s)' % (self.role.role_name,
                                     self.curriculum.course_period.course.course_abbreviation,
                                     self.curriculum.module_period.module.module_abbreviation,
                                     self.staff.staff_full_name)

class Staffs(models.Model):
    staff_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admission_number = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                                        unique=True,
                                        help_text="Enter 5 digits",
                                        validators=[numeric_only, MinLengthValidator(5)])
    staff_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=70,
                                       help_text="Enter staff's full name",
                                       validators=[letters_only])
    created_by = UserForeignKey(auto_user_add=True,
                                editable=False,
                                related_name="staff_created_by",
                                db_column="created_by")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                      editable=False)
    updated_by = UserForeignKey(auto_user=True,
                                editable=False,
                                related_name="staff_updated_by",
                                db_column="updated_by")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,
                                      editable=False)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Roles, through='Designations')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "arc_staffs"
        verbose_name_plural = "Staffs"
        ordering = ['staff_id']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (S%s)' % (self.staff_full_name, self.admission_number)
```

I have made a forms.py to get the admission_number(field in Staffs model)

```
class AssignRolesForm(forms.Form):
    admission_no = forms.CharField(max_length=40,
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(
                                     attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'aria-describedby': 'add-btn'}))
```

heres my html:

```
<form action="{% url 'setInstructor' %}" method="POST" role="form">
                       {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                {{ form.instructor }}
                              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="add-btn">assign</button>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Assuming that when i submit the form i would like for the admission_number entered in the form to reference into the Staffs model then get its PK to be saved into the staff field and for the curriculum and role fields to reference PK 1 of their respective models. How would i write my function in views.py to save a record into Designations model when 'submit' is clicked

heres the views.py that i tried but did not work

```
@require_POST
def setInstructor(request):
    form = AssignRolesForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        staff = Staffs(admission_number=form.cleaned_data['instructor'])
        role = Roles(pk=1)
        curriculum = Curricula(pk=1)
        designation = Designations(staff=staff, role=role, curriculum=curriculum)
        designation.save()

    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Can you show your setInstructor view so far? I'm not quite clear what you want to do.

Comment: @DanielRoseman my views function is added above

Comment: Your code looks incomplete, you reference a field called `instructor` yet the form does not contain one.  also, you are instantiating `Roles` and `Curricula` with a primary key of `1` - if it is in use, you will have an integrity exception. Also, in `Staffs` the `addmission_number` is unique and you are inserting the potentially same `addmission number. You should lookup `get_or_create` which may be useful for some of your use cases. Also, please post complete code. Otherwise, you are unlikely to get any meaningful help